# Error in callback for watcher “get_settings”: “TypeError: Cannot read property ‘general’ of undefined”

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Please help me out, how to handle this error i cant seem to handle this out as i am new to vue.
what im doing is getting data from server in store vuex with action. Now in component im accessing that data with getter in computed property and trying to watch that property but on component mount i get that error in console but functionality works fine.

```js
data: function() {
  return {
    settings_flags :{
      general: 0,
      privacy: 0,
      layouts: 0,
      message: 0
    }
  }
}
```

1: mounting

```js
mounted() {
  let self = this;
  self.userid = this.getUserId();
  this.$store.dispatch('getGallerySettings',self.req);
  self.initial_settings();
}
```

2: computed

```js
computed: {
  get_settings() {
    return this.$store.getters.getGallerySettings;
  }
}
```

3: watch

```js
watch: {
  'get_settings': {
    deep: true,
    handler() {
      let self =this;

      if (this.$_.isMatch(self.get_settings.gallery_settings.general,self.initialSettings.gallery_settings.general) == false) {
        self.settings_flags.general = 1;
      } else {
        self.settings_flags.general = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share with us what your specific error is.

Generally this sort of error happens when data is not yet present when the component is created, but appears later. When the data appears, everything works. The error will disappear if you check for the missing data before using it.

Comment: yes i know initially data does not appears which is causing error but i am not figuring out how to handle it.
i am using watch on computed property which is getting data from server as it take some time to load thats why watch gives me error of undefined and if i check length of property like if length is greater than 0 than do watch due to it this never watches data

Comment: I really need the precise error text to help you further.

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "get_settings": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'general' of undefined"

found in

---> <GallerySettings> at resources/assets/js/components/gallery/gallerySetting/gallery_settings.vue
       <Root>

TypeError: Cannot read property 'general' of undefined
    at VueComponent.handler (app.js:62446)
    at Watcher.run (app.js:33534)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (app.js:33282)
    at Array.<anonymous> (app.js:32138)
    at flushCallbacks (app.js:32059)

Comment: Do you have any clue on solving this? I got a similar error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your watcher is looking for a property 'general' that is a child of gallery_settings.

```
get_settings.gallery_settings.general
```

In the meantime in data you have a property general that is a child of 'settings_flags'. Those two don't line up. So make sure that either your watcher is looking for something that exists when the component starts up, or tell your watcher to only start watching '    get_settings.gallery_settings.general' when 'get_settings.gallery_settings' actually exists.

```
if (get_settings.gallery_settings) { do something } #pseudocode
```

I'm not sure that's your problem, but it might be.